# How to make sure urllib.urlretrieve runs non-interactively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

Sometimes `urllib.urlretrieve` prompts the user for username and password.

This is, frankly, surprising, because I expected `urllib.urlretrieve` to be non-interactive.

Is it possible to make it simply raise an exception when authentication is required? If not, is there an equally simple alternative, or should I

```
os.system('curl ...')
```

Comment: Maybe you could try defining your own `URLopener` subclass and overwrite `get_user_passwd`/`prompt_user_passwd` in it (and pass an instance of that to `urlretrieve`)?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to access url which requires username and password intentionally and I'm getting

```
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02A279E0>).
```

Do you get the same? If yes you can just except this error in your try except block

Comment: No, but I wish I did.

Comment: The docs say `FancyURLopener` should prompt the user. Maybe you are not running this from the terminal?